# Why is AgCl considered a good electrolyte? Isnt it sparingly soluble?

Tags: electrochemistry

My textbook says AgCl has degree of dissosciation as almost 1 but its sparingly soluble. While solving to find Ksp of AgCl using kohlrauschs law we have said that molar conductivity of sparingly soluble salts in normal concentration is almost same as at infinite dilution as degree of dissosciation is 1.

Answer (score 5):

"Good electrolyte" is not explicitly defined term in electrochemistry. It is more probably used in context of electrochemistry related engineering in sense of degree of its applicability in particular technical solution, giving to the solution high enough conductivity.

Electrochemistry in context of physical chemistry as a science defines

- a weak electrolyte with the dissociation degree  $\ll 1$ for
  $\ce{AB(solv) <=> A+(solv) + B-(solv)}$
- a strong electrolyte with the dissociation degree $\approx 1$.

Note that this does not involve the electrolyte solubility.

- A weak electrolyte as acetic acid is miscible with water in any ratio.
- A strong electrolyte as silver chloride or baryum sulfate  have very limited solubility.

Note that being strong/weak electrolyte is rather condition dependent and usually related to typical range of not too much diluted solution.

- Weak electrolytes like acetic acid converge to being strong electrolyte going to infinite dilution.
- Strong electrolytes with higher ion charges like MgSO4 become not so strong at higher concentrations, forming ionic pairs.

Comment: does that mean that degree of dissociation is defined only for already solvated compounds? my understanding based on your reply is that acetic acids degree of dissosciation is low cuz CH3COOH(aq) dissoscaites less but for AgCl(s) the little part that becomes AgCl(aq) fully converts to its ions?

Comment: Yes, the degree of dissociation is defined for $\ce{AB(solv) <=> A+(solv) + B-(solv)}$. // Otherwise, you could not reasonably define it, as its value would depend on amount of present solid.

Comment: Interesting! A strong electrolyte upon reaching its saturation point would form fewer Ionic molecules before crystal formation. A careful study of supersaturation could possibly explain what is happening. The last comment indicates that since crystal formation is dependent on initiation sites, nucleation, the amount of solid present is a possible factor.

Comment: @jimchmst MgSO4 reportedly forms significant portion of ionic pairs in sea water, what is still far from being saturated solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_association   (Burgess, John (1978). Metal Ions in Solution. Chichester: Ellis Horwood. ISBN 978-0-85312-027-8.Chapter 12, Kinetics and Mechanism: Complex formation")